# Get rid of duplicated master branch

Tags: git

We have a project that uses two git repositories. One is a read-only one (let's call it A) and we have full control over the other one (let's call it B).

Now, my colleague made a new "master" branch on our B repository, but A repository already had a "master" branch (he wasn't connected to the A repository at that time, so that's probably why). This is greatly confuses my local git tools (actually it messes with the B repo too).

Now we have something like (based on a graph from source tree):

```
                            B/master
                             \
     B/my-branch1         /- 13 -\
      \                  /        \
       7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 14 - 15
      /
 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - master
                      \
                       16 - 17 - 18 - 19
                      /
                     B/my-branch2
```

**I need this B/master to go away.**

I tried deleting the remote "master" branch, but I can't. Quite possibly the remote B repo still needs it's "master" branch (probably should be at revision 6). I also tried resetting the "master" branch, but local tools are confused about which branch is it. When I check directly on my remote repository "master" branch contains revisions 1,2,7,8,9,10,11,13. My local git tools recognize master branch as 1,2,3,4,5,6 and B/master as detached branch.

Can I fix this mess remotely and if not, what do I need to do locally and what do I need in the remote repository to fix this?

Comment: What command did you use when you tried to delete the remote `master` branch?  What error did you get?

Comment: @RichardHansen I don't remember the exact command, but I must have been on the right track, because I got the "By default, deleting the current branch is denied..." or some such. I ended up recreating the repo to solve my issues, but now I can see what might have help me fix the issue. It turned out that I should have deleted the "B/master" while retaining it as the remote head (sound impossible). Normally one should switch head before deleting master branch, but web interfaces for the repo required the head to be set to master. This situation only occurs on a freshly made repo on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly not the best solution, but I solved my issues, by disconnecting my copy of the project, fixing bad branches and than pushing it into a new repo.

I had to do this, because I had limited access to the remote repo (had to do everything through support) and for one reason or another the remote server required the Head to be set to "master" (if it was set to something else, web interface for the repo broke, though the repo appeared to work). This effectively made it impossible to delete the "master" branch. What's interesting is the fact that a fresh repo has no "master" branch, yet has "master" set as Head (so a better solution to my problem would require recreating this state somehow).

I'm afraid those might be quirks specific to the server provider of my repo.